# Is there any way to increment the minor and revision numbers also with each build?

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins

We know that in an AssemblyVersion.cs file, the Assembly Version is specified as [Major].[Minor].[Build].[Revision]. I am able to increment the build number in Jenkins using assembly-version-plugin, But not Minor and Revision number as required. Please help me with this.